# Formulário para alterar variável para um cálculo na mesma view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formulário, view, controller

Estou começando com o Rails.

Tenho uma view que recebe informações do banco de dados e por meio de métodos de um model fazem diversos cálculos.

Por exemplo:

```
<% @profundidade = 0.5 %>

<% @prnt = 90 %>

<% @analises.each do |analise| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= valor_duascasas(analise.nctotalcomarea * @profundidade * @prnt) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Desejo criar um formulário que altere esse valor de `@profundidade` e `@prnt`.

Answer (score 1):

Você não faz isso na view, e sim no controller.

Receba as 2 variáveis como parâmetro, efetue o calculo e retorne os dados prontos para a view.

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando a resposta sobre parâmetros. Basta você enviar as duas variáveis como parâmetro na url (por exemplo http://localhost:3000/analises/?prnt=9&profundidade=0.5)

Depois disso, você pode acessar as variáveis tanto no controlador quanto na view, pela variável params e setar esses valores padrão caso não receba nenhum. Por exemplo:

```erb
<% @profundidade = params[:profundidade] || 0.5 %>

<% @prnt = params[:prnt] || 90 %>
```

PS: Sugiro ainda passar essas variáveis para o controlador e só acessar elas na view.